# Invalid Lookbehind With HTML Tags

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3, pcre

The idea is to match all blocks of code that come after `h3>` and before `</section` where the matches will actually be a number of `<p>...</p>` elements

This is actually in sublime text 3 (find all in file), with the intention of wrapping all these blocks in `<div><\div>` tags (thanks to emmet plugin, `ctrl+shift+g`)...

...so if you know it should work, tell me and I'll stop worrying about it. Or if you can come up with an alternative way of archieving the same goal, that would also be awesome.

My idea is:

```
(?<=<\/h3\s*)<p(?:\n|.)*(?!\s*<\/section)
```

Broken down it would come to be something like...

```
(?<=<\/h3\s*)        # lookbehind for </h3 and any space including newline
<p(?:\n|.)*          # match, if it follows, <p and anything...
(?!\s*<\/section)    # if not followed by spaces and <\section
```

I'm getting `Invalid lookbehind asserion...` and it seems to be the first asterisk.

Is this correct in python 3?

EDITED: \s includes \n, changed that. Also, see comment about PCRE if having similar issues

Comment: Sublime Text actually uses the PCRE regex engine, not Python's

Comment: In Perl, you can usually use `\K` to work around the lack of variable-length lookbehinds. `m{</h3\s*\K<p.*(?!\s*</section)}s` (Note that `\s` includes `\n` in Perl, and probably everywhere else too.)

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I'll look into writing it in PCRE

Comment: `.*(?!\s*</section)` surely doesn't do the right thing. I think you're looking for `(?:(?!\s*</section).)*`

Comment: @ikegami I noticed about \s, thanks, don't know why I thought sublime would need both, it doesn't

Comment: Ok, saw the followed by and not followed by mistake now... took me some time!

Comment: This worked: `h3>\s*\K<p(?:\n|.)*?(?=\s*</section)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems were:

First, as MattDMo commented, Sublime uses PCRE regex engine.

Second, the third borken down part of the regex, `(?!\s*<\/section)` was a negative lookahead, and it should be a positive one (if followed by, and not if NOT followed by). That would be `(?=\s*</section)`.

Third , In PCRE lookbehinds can't contain `*` because they have to be of fixed length. This can be solved with the `\K` escape, that resets the start of the current whole match, i.e., matches if followed by the, not included, previous to \K match.

And lastly, in the second broken down section of the regex, `<p(?:\n|.)*` should include `?` at the end, becoming `<p(?:\n|.)*?`. That way the match is lazy (non-greedy).

What woked was:

```
h3>\s*\K<p(?:\n|.)*?(?=\s*</section)
```